# Need a hint with permutations and pigeonhole-principle question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, pigeonhole-principle

let $\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3\in S_{28}$. Help me prove that there are two sub-sequences of 28 with length 4  $i_1< i_2 <i_3<i_4,\ and\ \  j_1<j_2<j_3<j_4$ so that $\pi_q(i_n)=\pi_p(j_n)$ for some $1\leq p \neq q \leq 3$